# org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect is deprecated

Tags: java, hibernate

I've just added configuration for Hibernate to my application and IntelliJ Idea is complaining that this dialect is deprecated:

```xml
<property name="hibernate.dialect">
   org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
</property>
```

Does not seem to be a clear solution on the internet, any suggestions?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You need to use [`org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/PostgreSQL82Dialect.html) instead.

This is documented in [`PostgreSQLDialect`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/PostgreSQLDialect.html) Javadoc:

> Deprecated. 
>   use PostgreSQL82Dialect instead

Note however that you should use the dialect that best matches the PostgreSQL JDBC driver you are using ([list here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html)). For example, if you are using PostgreSQL 9.4 or later, use [`PostgreSQL94Dialect`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/PostgreSQL94Dialect.html) instead.

Comment: I am a bit confused about it. I have postgres 10 (docker) and the PostgresSQL JDBC: 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.8'. Can I easily use the last version of the dialect, meaning PostgreSQL10Dialect?

Comment: note that this has been deprectated in hibernate 6.0 and it's actually the other way around now. Gotta love java