# Spring Boot JPA - Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Boot JPA application. Whenever I attempt to run it, It fails:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
```

I have looked at related questions here, but most seem to relate to issues where the DB is not already up, the credentials incorrect, etc. However, I am able to connect just fine with the PSQL client, so this cannot be the issue. I have tried it both with and without the platform and driver specified in my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://xxxx/my_db
spring.datasource.username=xxx
spring.datasource.password=xxx
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Furthermore, above the error, the application actually prints out the following:

```
2019-02-15 10:02:40.134  INFO 43204 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
```

What might be the issue? This application was actually working; however, I switched development machines recently and now cannot connect. I have disabled the firewall on my machine to see if that could be the issue but without success. Again, I am able to connect through PSQL, so I am really not sure what to think.

The stack trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManager' defined in class path resource [com/midamcorp/insuranceui/AppConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.persistence.EntityManager]: Factory method 'entityManager' threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846)
~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:139) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at com.midamcorp.insuranceui.EntryFrame.main(EntryFrame.java:55) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.persistence.EntityManager]: Factory method 'entityManager' threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:116) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.addConnections(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:363) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:260) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections$Builder.build(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:401) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:179) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:904) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:935) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79) ~[javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar:2.2]
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54) ~[javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar:2.2]
        at com.midamcorp.insuranceui.AppConfig.entityManager(AppConfig.java:29) ~[main/:na]
        at com.midamcorp.insuranceui.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1d809dad.CGLIB$entityManager$7(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
        at com.midamcorp.insuranceui.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1d809dad$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6a4ae74c.invoke(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at com.midamcorp.insuranceui.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1d809dad.entityManager(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        ... 65 common frames omitted
```

Comment: may be check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33725589/org-hibernate-dialect-postgresqldialect-is-deprecated

Comment: That is certainly good to know @Deadpool. It did not help in my particular case, but I sure was not aware that the value was deprecated. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 13):

I believe you have your dialect property set wrong

`spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect`

should be

`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect`

Comment: I am seeing this error after upgrading to spring boot version to 2.2.5.RELEASE

Comment: This solved the problem for me. I was getting this error. It was working fine in 2.1.4 but starting giving the issue in 2.3.0 for spring boot.

Comment: This will not work if you have to connect to 2 different database vendors such as DB2 and Oracle for example.  How would you set hibernate dialect in that case?

Comment: This will not work if you have to connect to 2 different database vendors such as DB2 and Oracle for example.  How would you set hibernate dialect in that case?

Comment: @pixel As far as I remember you can prefix the properties with oracle and db2 to create unique keys to load. Then you will need to tell spring to load 2 different JPA beans for each property set.

Answer (score 6):

When I get

> Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set

Above this error, there is something else was wrong, one time I got:

> sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user 'tenant2'@'localhost' to database 'tenant2'.

Another time is about "serverTimeZone". So my answer is to look the error above, that is your root cause.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, any error which prevents Spring JPA to connect to the DB results in this error, with no specific information. Examples of misconfigurations are:

- Bad DB URL
- Bad user/password

And more difficult to detect were the cases where

My SQL server was not configured for an specific timezone, so adding **`&serverTimezone=xxx`** (as @Janet already pointed out)

to the DB url solved the issue. e.g

```
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/dbname?autoReconnect=true&serverTimezone=UTC
```

Also I experienced problems with SSL credentials one particular environment, and adding **`&useSSL=false`** solved the issue. Now my connection URL looks like

```
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/dbname?autoReconnect=true&serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=false
```

Comment: Man this is what solved it for me, that's crazy. My error didn't even mention how there was a database connection issue. How'd you figure this out??

Answer (score 2):

The name of property is fine, it's the class that you defined that causes the problem. `PostgreSQLDialect` is deprecated. Change it into, for example:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
```

which is for postgres 9.5. More info [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/PostgreSQL95Dialect.html). If you have other version of postgres, you can find the right version of dialect class.

Comment: Thanks, but still not working. I am actually using PostgreSQL 10 on the server, but, after searching through the docs, 9.5 seemed to be the latest dialect that was available. Plus, I thought Spring JPA usually was able to automatically detect the dialect? Still not sure what the issue is; any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For me I need a config class

```
@Configuration
public class HikariConfig {
    @Autowired
    Environment environment;


@Bean(name = "dataSource")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
    dataSource.setJdbcUrl(environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.hikari.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.hikari.password"));
    dataSource.setCatalog("*****");
    /**
     * HikariCP specific properties. Remove if you move to other connection pooling library.
     **/
    dataSource.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", true);
    dataSource.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", 25000);
    dataSource.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", 20048);
    dataSource.addDataSourceProperty("useServerPrepStmts", true);
    dataSource.addDataSourceProperty("initializationFailFast", true);

    dataSource.setPoolName(environment.getProperty("microdb.datasource.hikari.poolName"));
    dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize")));
    dataSource.setMinimumIdle(Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.hikari.minimumIdle")));
    dataSource.setIdleTimeout(Long.parseLong(environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout")));
    dataSource.setMaxLifetime(Long.parseLong(environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime")));
    dataSource.setConnectionTimeout(Long.parseLong(environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout")));

    return dataSource;
}}
```

And in application.properties file I setup:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxxxx:xxx:xxxx
spring.datasource.hikari.username=xxxxx
spring.datasource.hikari.password=xxxxx
spring.datasource.hikari.minimumIdle=5
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=20
spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.poolName=HikariCP
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=2000000
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=30000
```